# How to make blog posts have their own urls?

Tags: posts

When I post a blog post, the blog post doesn't appear with a separate url -- it just appears under http://richardclunan.com/blog and there's no button to edit the url when I'm on the Edit Post page.

How do i make blog posts have their own urls?

Comment: Looks like there's something either wrong in your theme or, more likely, you have something funny set under Settings -> Permalinks.

Comment: I'd like my posts to be at richardclunan.com/blog/name-of-post -- i'm not sure what to change in Permalinks -- here's what my settings are: https://img.skitch.com/20120127-pui92nan3ujf2fmjhyu6da375a.jpg

Comment: I just noticed the url in Permalinks read " /http:/richardclunan.com/blog " -- so there's a slash in the wrong place -- so i've changed it to this: https://skitch.com/richardclunan/ght8n/permalink-settings-richard-clunan-direct-response-fundraising-copywriter-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Permalinks (in settings) to /%postname%/, you set the blog location in settings->general, not in your permalinks. Permalinks builds on the Settings->General URL

Comment: thanks. I set 'Blog' as 'Posts page' at Settings>Reading. And at Permalinks I've now set it not as /%postname%/ but as /blog/%postname%/ -- is that the right way to do it?

Comment: No, you should have `Settings->General->Wordpress Address` read `http://richardclunan.com/blog/` and `Settings->Permalinks->Custom Structure` should read `/%postname%/`